# How can I test for calls ignoring params arguments in NSubstitute?

Tags: c#, testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I have code which looks like:

```
eventPublisher.Publish(new SpecificEvent(stuff),
                        EventStreams.Stream1,
                        EventStreams.Stream2);
```

which is calling a method defined as :

```
Publish<T>(T eventToPublish, params EventStream[] streams) where T : IEvent;
```

in something I want to test. This event publication is the most important thing to happen in what I want to test, but I am not interested in testing which event streams it publishes to. How can I make a substitute in NSubstitute to test that this is called with an appropriate event, without concerning myself with the params? Thus far, I have:

```
eventPublisher.Received(1).Publish(Arg.Any<SpecificEvent>());
```

This, of course, does not match the call with two streams. Is there a way to match a params argument using NSubstitute, ignoring the number of parameters passed in?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Params` enables methods to receive variable numbers of parameters. With `params`, the arguments passed to a method are changed by the compiler to elements in a temporary array. This array is then used in the receiving method.

You can use `Arg.Any<EventStream[]>` to match a params argument, ignoring number of parameters passed in.

```
eventPublisher.Received(1).Publish(Arg.Any<SpecificEvent>(), Arg.Any<EventStream[]>())
```

Comment: I'm slightly embarassed that when I tried this, I must've got something else wrong! Thankyou for the quick and correct answer.

Comment: I like to leave it for a couple of hours, in case some stupendous answer comes along and stuns me - now accepted.